# Display Symfony command output in Capistrano V3 script

Tags: symfony, command, output, capistrano

I use Capistrano to deploy SF projects.
So, to call a SF command, I use :

```
invoke 'symfony:console', :'assets:install'
```

Let's say I want to display command output, how can I do ? I tried with "capture" but didn't manage to make it work.

Many thanks for answers,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install [capistrano/symfony](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony) gem ?

Then call a SF command like this:

```
symfony_console('assetic:dump')
```

And set capistrano with debug log level and pretty format:

```
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug
```

At least it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, you point me in the right direction : my GemFile was using a freaking old Symfony Capistrano version. All good now with your inputs !